# User registration across multiple websites

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account

I have three separate magento installations linked up in such a way that one site behaves as the main website and the other two sites can be accessed from the main site by selecting from a drop down list in the main website. I would like users/customers to register for the other two sites through the main website. Can somebody kindly tell me how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 different installations and you couldn't merge them in a single installation, maybe the most easy solution is implement a module in all sites and hook an observer (after registration) then by API replicate the user in the other 2 sites.

Be aware of run a pre-validation first to avoid customer duplication errors i mean, you could run a manual validation between the 3 stores before turn on that functionality.

BTW I don't remember if you can access to the unencrypted password in that event (`customer_register_success`) if not, you should override the `AccountController` or the `CustomerModel` to perform the soap/rest request, but to ensure that the customer registration works as expected, you could use the controller or model to save the password in registry (and maybe a flag) and based on that flag (and the customer create result) perform (or not) the API Request inside the `customer_register_success` event observer.